# Combining jQuery UI and HotTowel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, durandal, hottowel

I'm getting back into web development a bit after having been kind of out of it for the past 10 years or so, and I'm overwhelmed by all the new technologies that I'm having to catch up with, ASP.NET, MVC, jQuery, SPA, Knockout, etc. I don't know the second thing about jQuery and my experience with ASP.NET is very limited. I have a little familiarity with ASP.NET WebForms, but MVC (and the rest) is totally new to me.

After seeing how many technologies there were, and not knowing which route to explore in my new project, I saw that Hot Towel seems to be a template that combines all the latest stuff into one nice package, so I decided to get the Hot Towel template and start an ASP.NET MVC4 SPA project with it.

Now I'm trying to integrate with our in-house UI framework (which has been developing without me over the past few years). I decided to try to update the Details page in the Hot Towel template to have some content. I added a simple `<span>`, and all's well and good. But if I try to add what I understand to be a jQuery-widget-based component (?), I get nothing. Even for the simplest test of adding content via jQuery, I get nothing:

```
<section>
    <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>
    <span>Test this</span>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#testDiv").append("Testing");
    </script>
</section>
```

I see the `span`, but not the modified `div`. And I can't see any of this content in the source ("View source") or the IE9 console (not surprising given the nature of SPA, but what should I do about it?). And the Visual Studio Page Inspector seems to be totally useless (can't get past the splash screen).

What is the proper method of adding elements to the UI under the HotTowel/jQuery/MVC/SPA/KockoutJS/Breeze/Durandal model? All these new frameworks are driving my crazy.

**Edit** some more details: The jQuery stuff works fine when I move it to the main page of the SPA, but when I have it on the Details "page" it doesn't work. I suspect it has something to do with the SPA nature of this application and how the content of alternate views are delivered not as an entire page, but as updated content for the main page.

**Edit** after further investigation, I have discovered the existence of a view model named "detail" which is probably related to this detail view code I have posted. This is the code from the view model:

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'Details';
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: title
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about howtowel.. But if you try adding `<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){alert('test');});
    </script>` to the bottom of your page just above the ending `</body>` tag do you get the alert?

Comment: No, I don't get an alert when the SPA loads or when I switch to the details view. I'm not clear what $(document).ready would mean in an SPA where there is only one document for the entire application life cycle. BTW, I don't have a `</body>` tag because the details page is just a segment of a whole page. That's where I tried adding it, not on the main page where the `<body>` tag is.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me that your jQuery files must not be loaded granted I have no idea about HotTowel

Comment: Okay run your original jQuery from there and see if it works.

Comment: On the main page is there anywhere you see that it is importing `jquery.js` files etc..  e.g. `<script src="/Common/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` You would need to import jQuery into every page that is using it I believe.

Comment: Because this is an MVC SPA, that gets imported into the root page by Bundleconfig.cs when it adds jQuery among the other files to a bundle to implicitly handle minification in release mode. If I view the source of the main page, I do see that all the jQuery files are there. But I don't understand the architecture of SPA well enough to know how the details page content is loaded. It must be some sort of AJAX call that loads and replaces a piece of the DOM. Let me emphasize, this is an SPA so there is only one page as far as the browser is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is probably executing but cannot find the div. To correct manipulate div put your jquery code to in a function and trigger that function using attached/compositionComplete callback for duranadal 2.0 or viewAttached callback for durandal 1.x

1.x link - https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/docs/1.2/Composition.html.md#view-attached

2.0 link - http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/

```
  // in your detail view model, if using durandal 1.x
  define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'Details';
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: title,
        viewAttached : function(view){
                      // view is the root element of your detail view and is passed in 
                      // by durandal
                       $(view).append("Testing");
                     }
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
  });

  // in your detail view model, if using durandal 2.0, you have two options
  define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'Details';
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: title,
        attached : function(view, parent){
                       // view is the root element of your detail view
                       // and is passed in by durandal
                       $(view).append("Testing first method");
                     },
        compositionComplete: function(view, parent){
                       // view is the root element of your detail view
                       // and is passed in by durandal
                       $(view).append("Testing second method");
                     }
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
  });
```

Comment: How does detailViewModel relate/connect to the rest of the code? It appears to be a local variable in your example.

Comment: Could you post the code for your detail view model? Depending on whether your detail view model is a breeze entity or your own module, these handlers would be added with different techniques.

Comment: I thought the code I had posted was my detail view model in its entirety, straight from the hottowel template with a few lines added. But being very new to all these new technologies, I'm not clear on what a view model is. Do you have access to the hottowel template? My project is basically a plain vanilla hottowel MVC4 project with almost no alterations right now.

Comment: I recommend you play with samples at https://github.com/dFiddle. They use plan HTML and javascript so no ASP.NET MVC or DB etc. These are much better to learn Durandal features.

Comment: I think my question is much more basic than the sample code at dFiddle is going to help me understand: Is it valid to include jQuery-UI based code in a details template/file provided in a HotTowel-based application? If not, why not? It is because I need to be aware of Durandal or KnockoutJS syntax?

Comment: I have discovered the code for my view model and added it to my question. Does this provide any new insights?

Comment: Aha.. we are close now. I have edited my post with your code. I think hot towel uses durandal 1.1 so the first module definition should work for you. Also, I find the chrome or firebug console to be better help for debugging. IE11 seems to have a better console.

Comment: Awesome, it works! BTW, the template I picked up for Hot Towel appears to be using Durandal 2.0. (I left the div in the html file and moved the jQuery code with the `$` thingamajigs into detail.js - my view model)